# Нужно ли мне публиковать код, если я использую docker-контейнер OnlyOffice Document Server, с лицензией AGPL-3?

Tags: лицензирование, opensource, onlyoffice

Есть коммерческий сервис, в котором модуль, который посредством RestAPI использует конвертер OnlyOffice. Я не использую и не модифицирую код внутри контейнера, вся работа происходит через HTTP API

Нужно ли мне в таком случае публиковать код сервиса под лицензией AGPL-3? Я так понимаю, что сервис не является "производной работой", т.к. не содержит код OnlyOffice, а значит я не должен публиковать код

Comment: Возможно вам также стоит написать тот же вопрос (только на английском) в сеть [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Речь скорее не про "производную работу", но про зависимость от использования.
Примеров и пояснений в сети [множество](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107883/agpl-what-you-can-do-and-what-you-cant), и если коротко, то нужно публиковать под AGPL3.
У Google хорошо [расписано](https://opensource.google/documentation/reference/using/agpl-policy) )
На гугл же, кстати, [ссылается](https://fossa.com/blog/open-source-software-licenses-101-agpl-license/) "авторитет" FOSSA

Comment: А если я вынесу этот модуль отдельно, сделаю ему API, выложу его код под APGL3, а весь остальной код под другой лицензией и он будет использовать API отдельного модуля? Я читал, что это вроде должно работать

Comment: суть от этого не изменится, agpl3 продукта, который используется (не распространяется, но именно используется) по сети любым способом будет накладывать на Вас обязательства.